# Make a website title scroll in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I would like my website title in tabs to scroll, when the text is long enough to make it scroll and only until the end of the title, instead of making it continue scrolling like a wheel(?).

Basically, as an example, imagine the title is: "This is my website's title which is really long." This title should scroll.

First or initial state should be: "This is my website's title", then it will start scrolling until it shows "itle which is really long."

And then it **should not** show something like "really long. This is my we" ... but instead, it should go back to the initial state: "This is my website's title".

And as another example, imagine the title is "Website title", now this title shouldn't scroll.

I'm not sure what's the exact amount of visible characters in tabs in different browsers, but I counted in Google Chrome and they are 26.

I'm currently using this code:

```
(function titleScroller(text) {
        document.title = text;
        console.log(text);
        setTimeout(function () {
            titleScroller(text.substr(1) + text.substr(0, 1));
        }, 500);
    }("This is my website's title which is really long."));
```

Which I foung in another StackOverflow question, but this one makes the text scroll as I don't want.

Can someone help me to achieve the expected or desired behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share a live URL too which shows your current progress?

Comment: 1990's all over again!  So when you detect it gets to the end, set the title back to the original state.

Comment: Probably not doable due to the width of the displayed title being unknown (which means you cannot detect when it hits the end). You could, however, scroll from "123..." to "...789" to "89 " to "9  " to "   " and then back again...

Comment: This is probably a bad idea if you want people to be able to bookmark your page and have a useful title.

Comment: I don't have live URL as I haven't published this because I want to test everything before.

Comment: All I have is that snippet, but I don't know javascript so I was looking for someone to help me.

But, @4castle is right about it. Is a bad idea. So, I will remove it from the site.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* detect when the title has reached the end ("itle which is really long.") since you cannot query the user's browser for the length of the title area (which depends on the browser's window size, the number of tabs open etc.). Therefore it is *not possible* to implement your idea.

You *could*, however, dynamically alter the favicon and let your page's title scroll exactly according to your requirements within the icon's well known bounded area. Welcome to the 90's, yay!